# raw javascript print items from json object to screen in list

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am writing a program in raw javascript. In this program I am calling a json object, which returns a list of items and their prices -

```
[
    {
        "shopName": "The Coffee Connection",
        "address": "123 Lakeside Way",
        "phone": "16503600708",
        "prices": [
            {
                "Cafe Latte": 4.75,
                "Flat White": 4.75,
                "Cappucino": 3.85,
                "Single Espresso": 2.05,
                "Double Espresso": 3.75,
                "Americano": 3.75,
                "Cortado": 4.55,
                "Tea": 3.65,
                "Choc Mudcake": 6.4,
                "Choc Mousse": 8.2,
                "Affogato": 14.8,
                "Tiramisu": 11.4,
                "Blueberry Muffin": 4.05,
                "Chocolate Chip Muffin": 4.05,
                "Muffin Of The Day": 4.55
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am trying to display each item as a list item `< li>` on my html page. I am looking for the same functionality as angular's ng-repeat directive. I have tried to append the a child node to the `<ul >`, however this didn't work as expected.

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <ul id="myList"></ul>
        <script src="js/getData.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My getData.js file looks as follows:

```
function loadJSONDoc() {
    var answer;
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            answer = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)

            var items = answer[0].prices[0];

            for (var index in items) {
                var node = document.getElementById("myList");
                var textnode = document.createTextNode(index + " : " + items[index]);
                node.appendChild(textnode);
            }
            document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(node);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/items", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    loadJSONDoc();
});
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
<ul>
   <li>Cafe Latte: $4.75</li>
   <li>Flat White: $4.75</li>
   <li>Cappucino: $3.85</li>
   <!-- etc............ -->
</ul>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Also, to note that I used `document.write(index + " : " + items[index] + "</ br > "` which worked, however, this is not what I am looking for, which I hope is evident from my description above.

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create `li` element, append `textnode` to it, and after that append `li` to the list:

```
for (var index in items) {
    var node = document.getElementById("myList");
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(index + " : " + items[index]);
    li.appendChild(textnode);
    node.appendChild(li);
}
```

Also make sure your HTML is valid. I'm talking about `<ul id="myList"></div>` things.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/bKl56vg7AkaiJZd7tFVx?p=preview

Comment: I apologise for the html error.
I removed a section of the html for the purpose of the question, and left the < /div> there by accident

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 things :

1. you never create `li` in your js code
2. you got an error in your HTML

**JS**

```
var node = document.getElementById("myList"); // this should be outside the loop

for(var index in items) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(index + " : " + items[index]);
  li.appendChild(textnode);
  node.appendChild(li);
}
```

and suppress

```
document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(node);
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="myList"></div>
```

should be

```
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```

Comment: thanks shikiryu, appreciate your help. Apologies for the html error. i removed some unnecessary section of the html for the purpose of the question, and left the < /div> there by accident. The answer above worked :-) As I can see the main issue was I never created the li element.

Answer (score 1):

A **clean** way in this case is to use a **table**. Because of the logic and because of a **better** and **solid CSS access** to your HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>name</td><td>price</td></tr>
    <tr><td>name</td><td>price</td></tr>
</table>
```

For example the CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 20px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

JS:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
var output = "<table>";
for(var name in obj[0].prices[0]) {
    output += "<tr><td>" + name + "</td>" + "<td>" + obj[0].prices[0][name] + "</td></tr>";
}
output += "</table>";
document.getElementById("myList").innerHTML = output;
```

**Demo**: http://embed.plnkr.co/6MNeKK/preview